# How to get data from my custom (entity) table?

Tags: magento-1.9, model, eav

```
<?php


$installer = $this;
echo 'Running This Installation: '.get_class($this)."\n <br /> \n"; 
$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()
->newTable($installer->getTable('amber_maintenance_mode'))

->addColumn('id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'identity'  => true,
    'unsigned'  => true,
    'nullable'  => false,
    'primary'   => true,
    ), 'Id')

->addColumn('state', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'State'
    )

->addColumn('created_by', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Created by'
    )

->addColumn('start_date', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATE, null, array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    'nullable' => true,
    'default' => null,
    'comment' => 'Start date'
    ), 'Start Date'
    )

->addColumn('end_date', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATE, null, array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    'nullable' => true,
    'default' => null,
    'comment' => 'End date'
    ), 'End Date'
    )

->addColumn('down_reason', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Down reason'
    );

$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Now trying to get data from table ....

```
$date = Mage::getModel('amber/maintenance_mode')->getCollection();
$date = Mage::getModel('amber_maintenance_mode')->getCollection();
$date = Mage::getModel('amber_maintenance/amber_maintenance_mode')->getCollection();
```

Nothing works ...... what I'm doing wrong ?
Which form is correct if any ?

Here is my config "required section" ;)

```
        <models>
        <amber_maintenance>
            <class>Amber_Maintenance_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>maintenance_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </amber_maintenance>

        <amber_maintenance_resource>
            <class>Amber_Maintenance_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <mode>
                        <table>amber_maintenance_mode</table>
                    </mode>
                </entities>

        </amber_maintenance_resource>   
    </models>

    <resources>
        <maintenance_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Amber_Maintenance</module>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </maintenance_setup>
        <maintenance_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </maintenance_write>
        <maintenance_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </maintenance_read>
    </resources>
```

Comment: please add your `config.xml` and model file code

Comment: `$date = Mage::getModel('amber_maintenance/mode')->getCollection();` should get you your data.

Comment: That's what I expected, but it won't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your `models` tag like below,

```
<models>
    <amber_maintenance>
        <class>Amber_Maintenance_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>amber_maintenance_resource</resourceModel>
    </amber_maintenance>
    <amber_maintenance_resource>
        <class>Amber_Maintenance_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <mode>
                    <table>amber_maintenance_mode</table>
                </mode>
            </entities>
    </amber_maintenance_resource>   
</models>
```

Now use,

```
Mage::getModel('amber_maintenance/mode')->getCollection();
```

Or

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('amber_maintenance/mode_collection');
```

Comment: Updated ..... still nothing, on screen all I can see is "bool(false)" in left top corner just above header ;)

Comment: Can you confirm if you have data in your table, also check if you can load a single object with id by using, `Mage::getModel('amber_maintenance/mode')->load(ID_OF_RECORD)`

Comment: Nope, nothig. $single = Mage::getModel('amber_maintenance/mode')->load(1); Blank screen :)

Comment: Can you confirm with this link if you are not missing any file or code. https://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/04/creating-a-magento-custom-model/

Comment: Yes I can confirm, everything works except it wont fetch any data from table using magento methods. If add a mysql query I can pull data from any table, but to build grid with data I must be able to do it using Magento collection ....bla bla bla ;)

Comment: Can you see any errors? Check `var/log`, enable developer mode, uncomment `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` line in your `index.php` file.

Comment: No, no errors only nothing fetched - bool(false). Will check logs, one sec.

Comment: the only error in log was undefined variable .... already removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53040/discussion-between-jaimin-sutariya-and-robert-a).

Answer (score 3):

I think one of the problem is that you have a node

```
<resourceModel>maintenance_mysql4</resourceModel>
```

and then you are using

```
    <amber_maintenance_resource>
        <class>Amber_Maintenance_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <mode>
                    <table>amber_maintenance_mode</table>
                </mode>
            </entities>
    </amber_maintenance_resource>
```

With your notation, you should write :

```
    <resourceModel>amber_maintenance_resource</resourceModel>
```

Comment: Good spot ;) Checking ;)

Comment: Still nothing but .... at least no blank screen :)

Comment: $collection2 = Mage::getModel('amber_maintenance/mode')->getCollection();

Comment: this method causing "blank screen"